# No mouse and keyboard input after updated to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, keyboard, mouse

I was on Ubuntu 18.04. I decided to update to 22.04 today using `update-manager-core`. The updater won't let me upgrade to 22.04 so I upgrade to 20.04 instead.

I found that I lost both keyboard and mouse input just after the login screen is loaded. I googled and found that I will have to install `xserver-xorg-input-all` in order to make them work.

I have no idea on how to do that without keyboard and mouse. I have tried almost everything:

1. recovery mode with network enabled
2. normal boot up with runlevel 3
3. normal boot up with tty2

Everything ended up fail resolving domains. I tried to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` and restart the `systemd-resolved`. The `systemd-resolved` keeps failing to restart.

I would like to know if there is any way I can get the mouse and keyboard working again.